# How to treat Button as a container in WatiN?

Tags: watin

`<button>` is a very well valid container in HTML standard yet WatiN DOM implementation does not support that behavior. Is there way to "cast" it to a container to query child elements of that button? My attempts to do it with `ElementContainer<TElement>` instances were in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We worked this around by creating a descendant of `ElementContainer<Button>` naming it `ContainerButton`. We used that whenever we wanted to refer to a button. It needs to have an `[ElementTag("button")]` attribute at top.